# Why I am getting AttributeError: 'Students' object has no attribute 'displayStudent'

Tags: python

Please let know why I am getting AttributeError: 'Students' object has no attribute 'displayStudent'

```
class Students:
       def __init__(self,name,age):
            self.name= name
            self.age= age


        def displayStudent(self):
               return("Student name is" + self.name + "and age is" + str(self.age))

stu = Students("Chad",15)
stu.displayStudent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some indentation error. Here's the correct code.

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def displayStudent(self):
        return "Student name is " + self.name + " and age is " + str(self.age)

stu = Students("Chad", 15)
stu.displayStudent()
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code I got an error in the class definition because `def displayStudent` was at a different indentation level from the `def __init__`.  Fixed it up and it works fine:

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def displayStudent(self) -> None:
        print(f"Student name is {self.name} and age is {self.age}")


stu = Students("Chad", 15)
stu.displayStudent()
```

```
Student name is Chad and age is 15
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This works fine , just check the indentation once.
You will get this error if the "displayStudent" method is outside the class "Students"